# What can i do to speed up the connection ("pairing" speed, not query speed) to my SQL online database?

Tags: c#, mysql, tcpclient

This is from the "update port" function for my Windows Forms application meant to toggle boolean values in the database in order for the values to be updated on an ESP8266. The latency is about 6 sec from you press the button till the ESP detects the change. I have determined that the slow part is when trying to reconnect, as executing all 3 requests required to respond to a button press happen very fast after the connection is made. Is there a way I can reduce this response time during connection?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toggleState("1");
        }

private void toggleState(string _utgang)
        {
            bool? state = cmd("SELECT Status FROM Traverskran WHERE Utgang = " + _utgang);
            if (state != null)
            {
                state = !state;
                cmd("UPDATE Traverskran SET Status = " + state.ToString() + " WHERE Utgang = " + _utgang);
            }
            updatePortStats();//Differentt function that does the same as cmd() but sends "SELECT * FROM Traverskran" and dumps it into a textBox
        }

private bool? cmd(string query)
        {
            string connectionString = ("server=" + url + ";" + "username=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";" + "database=" + databaseName + ";");
            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.CommandTimeout = 60;

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                bool? result = (reader.GetString(0) == "True");
                connection.Close();
                return result;
            }
            connection.Close();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            connection.Close();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you keep the connection open pre-emptively?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a new connection for each button press.  Open the connection when you open the form, and then use it to execute the required command on button press.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Connector/NET has a bug that makes opening the first connection (or all connections, if pooling is disabled) slow: [bug 80030](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80030).

It doesn't look like this bug has been fixed yet (in 8.0.10-rc); as a workaround you could switch to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), an OSS, high-performance alternative.